# Render image in left and right side of the screen alternatively

Tags: django-templates, wagtail

I want to render image in left and right side of the screen alternatively, dynamically in django template. I am not sure how to render it, like if it is 0th for loop counter the image should appear on the left of the screen, for the next iteration the image should render in right and so on.

[This is my requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Onnju.jpg)

[This is what I have achieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEglu.jpg)

Code below
**HTML**

```
{% block content %}

<!-- Banner -->
<div class="banner">
 <div class="container-fluid banner-content">
  <h3>{{page.banner_head}}</h3>
  {{page.banner_desc|richtext}}
 </div>
</div>

<section class="solution-section">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  {% for i in page.solutions.all %}
    <div class="row pb-5">

      <!-- Image -->
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="solution-image">
          <figure class="text-center">
            <h6>{{ i.img_text }}</h6>
          </figure>
          {% image i.sol_img original as img %}
          <img src="{{ img.url }}" class="img-fluid solution-index-image" alt="{{ img.alt }}">
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Text -->
      <div class="col-md-6 solution-desc">
        <h5>{{i.sol_head}}</h5>
          {{i.sol_desc|richtext}}
        <a href="{{i.sol_link}}" class="btn btn-md solution-btn">learn more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
</section>


{% endblock %}
```

**models.py**

```
class SolutionPage(Page):
banner_head = models.CharField('Banner Title', blank=True, max_length=255)
banner_desc = RichTextField('Banner Description', blank=True)

content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
    MultiFieldPanel([
        FieldPanel('banner_head'),
        FieldPanel('banner_desc'),
    ], heading='Banner Section'),

    InlinePanel('solutions', label='Solution Details'),

]

class Solution(Orderable):
sol_img = models.ForeignKey(
    'wagtailimages.Image',
    null = True,
    blank = True,
    on_delete = models.SET_NULL,
    related_name = '+',
    verbose_name = 'Solution Image',
)
img_text = models.CharField('Image Text', blank=True, max_length=255)
sol_head = models.CharField('Solution Heading', max_length=100, blank=True)
sol_desc = RichTextField('Solution Description', blank=True)
sol_link = models.CharField('Button Link', max_length=255, blank=True)
page = ParentalKey('SolutionPage', related_name='solutions')

panels = [
    ImageChooserPanel('sol_img'),
    FieldPanel('img_text'),
    FieldPanel('sol_head'),
    FieldPanel('sol_desc'),
    FieldPanel('sol_link')
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check odd/even in the template with `{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"2" %}`.

Comment: Just wondering if this answer worked for you.  If so, you could checkmark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: It is the one I was looking for. Thanks @Dan Swain.